# Sticky Footer and Content

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I'm using the sticky footer from here: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

The CSS looks like this:

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
height: 4em;
}
```

And the HTML like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I add another div within the wrapper is it possible to somehow set its height to fill the wrapper? Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should check out this sticky footer solution: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/. It does not use the push div.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `height: 100%;` to the div you want to add to your wrapper